# Send array with ajax in codeigniter

Tags: arrays, ajax, codeigniter

How can i pass an array with ajax?
My code in view:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#btn-send').click(function(){

    var value = {
              'name': $('#name').val(),
              'phone': $('#phone').val(),
              'mail': $('#mail').val(),
          };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo site_url('customer_add/test'); ?>',
        data: value,
        success: function(resp){
            $('#error').html(resp);
        }
    });
  });
});
```

My test method:

```
public function test5(){
    $data = $this->input->post["value"];
    $name = $data['name'];
    echo $name; 
}
```

In params - in the inspect element - there are data but in response, there's nothing to return.
What's wrong?
Thank's in advance.

Comment: try this `success : function(data) {
                //alert("ok");
    
            },
   error: function(er){
     alert("There is some error");
     console.log(er.responseText);
     
    }`

Comment: You are requesting the function test in ajax and in the code you are showing us function test5 in your server script ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You send data through ajax and you create a array of value with key:value pair when 
data send to server using post so you can get this whole array
in one single variable using.

```
public function test5(){
    $data = $this->input->post();
    $name = $data['name']; echo $name;
    $phone = $data['phone']; echo $phone;
    $mail = $data['mail']; echo $mail;
}
```

you dont have to mention value key in $data = $this->input->post["value"];

and the second thing

you are writing wrong syntax $this->input->post["value"];

the write syntax is $this->input->post("value");

but in $this->input->post("value"); case you cant get value because there is no key with value name.

Comment: Thanks quarksera :)
You're right. I changed it to data: {value: value}, and now i gat response but the problem is in this way, form validation doesn't work. At first it returns the validation errors but if i write data, the error are still the same and doesn't change!

Comment: do you use codeignitor form validation or custom give me some hint otherwise i cant do anything

Answer (score 1):

First, you can handle your error at the error section of `$.ajax` by `error: function(xhr) {},`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo site_url('customer_add/test'); ?>',
    data: {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        phone: $('#phone').val(),
        mail: $('#mail').val()
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        alert('error');
    },
    success: function(resp){
        $('#error').html(resp);
    }
});
```

Next, `type: 'POST'` means the form would post the fields out by the method `POST`. 
So that we can catch them by `$_REQUEST` or `$_POST`.

In Codeigniter, the way to catch the posted fields is `$this->input->post('name');`. 
There's an error in your syntax.

```
public function test5(){
    $data['name'] = $this->input->post('name');
    $data['phone'] = $this->input->post('phone');
    $data['mail'] = $this->input->post('mail');

    echo $data;
}
```

Hope it would be help.